# why the trigger is executing only once after workflow is fired?

Tags: trigger, workflow, field-update, order-of-execution

[image]I have a seen a illustration on execution of trigger in an execution context.
Such that Trigger A is executed which in turn Trigger B is executed followed by the execution of an workflow field update causes the trigger A to execute only once?

Comment: I think you need to provide a specific reference or details describing the circumstances in the example illustration in order for someone to answer your question. Without seeing the illustration, we'd merely be speculating. There are far too many possibilities for anyone to answer your question.

Comment: Hi crmprogdev,
I have added the picture, this is in reference with the book advanced apex programming by Dan Apple Man

Comment: I have Dan's book and it's a great book. It's not for beginners though. He uses static boolean variables to control flow of triggers and prevent recursion. I suspect that's the case in the illustration you're referencing. I don't know what edition that diagram is from. I have Ed 1 and 3. You don't tell us what he's describing that goes with it for me to say. Off-hand, I don't see that diagram in my copy of Ed 3.

Comment: With reference to the above diagram, I dont know why the trigger is not executing more than once after it is fired by the workflow update.

Comment: I see you've clarified your question and @DerekF has provided you with the correct answer. It's all about Trigger order of execution rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trigger(s) (and it is both Trigger 'A' and Trigger 'B' in your example) are only being executed once after the workflow field update because that's how Salesforce has decided to make things work.

If you go look at [the official order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), you'll see the following (emphasis mine)

> 11. If there are workflow field updates, updates the record again.
> 12. If the record was updated with workflow field updates, **fires before update triggers and after update triggers one more time (and only one more time)**, in addition to standard validations. Custom validation rules, duplicate rules, and escalation rules are not run again.

This is done to help prevent infinite recursion.